# Different states for UIButton not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have written this code to see different image states...

```
UIButton *btnComment = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnComment.tag=indexPath.row;
[btnComment addTarget:self action:@selector(goToComment:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

UIImage *img1 = [UIImage  imageNamed:@"commentbtndown.png"];
UIImage *img2 = [UIImage  imageNamed:@"commentbtnup.png"];
UIImage *img3 = [UIImage  imageNamed:@"commentbtnover.png"];

[btnComment setImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnComment setImage:img2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[btnComment setImage:img3 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btnComment setImage:img2 forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted+UIControlStateSelected)];

btnComment.frame            =CGRectMake(0, 100, 95, 25);
[cell addSubview:btnComment];

[img1 release];
[img2 release];
[img3 release];
```

but its not working, it is always showing me image 1.

p.s. I have added these images in the table view cell

Comment: Does your button goes disappear ?

Comment: nops...shows fine..working fine..but these damn states dont change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the `UIImage` objects with an autorelease method `imageNamed`, and you are releasing these objects afterwards, which cause your button to have invalid objects and because of that the images will not be displayed

Try removing this lines of code and your button will work

```
[img1 release];
[img2 release];
[img3 release];
```

And also, if you want the button to receive the touch events, you will have to add it to the contentView of your cell object, otherwise the button will be shown but you will not be able to tap it.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:btnComment]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well one problem with your code is that you should *not* be releasing those image variables. `imageNamed:` returns an autoreleased `UIImage`. I'm doubt that this is causing your problem, though.

Try using `|` instead of `+` for your fourth `setImage` call.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem with your code is where you add the button to your UITableViewCell. Instead of this:

`[cell addSubview:btnComment];`

You should add subviews to your cell's `contentView`:

`[cell.contentView addSubview:btnComment];`

But I'm also not certain that this may cause your problem...

Comment: are your images loaded ok? filenames spelled correctly, etc.?

Comment: yes they are,...and i have made my tableview's property to non selected can this be a problem?

Comment: Well.. you need to have at least `userInteractionEnabled = YES` in your tableView, cell and button.

Comment: Setting `multipleTouchEnabled = YES` on your cell might also help in some cases solve problems with delivery of events. And if you want only your button to respond to events, set `exclusiveTouch = YES` on your button.

Comment: Can a `UIButton` be in `UIControlStateHighlighted` and `UIControlStateSelected` states simultaneously? What happens if you temporarily remove that line of code?